# Why can't I git pull with irrelevant local changes?

Tags: git, git-pull

In git, you can't do `git pull` if you have any uncommitted modifications, giving the following error:

> error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
>
> error: please commit or stash them.

It works with untracked files though. I find this super annoying that I need to `git stash` every time I want to pull, even if my changes have nothing to do with the files being pulled.

Is there any workaround to allow pulling if my changes are not in conflict with the pulled ones? I don't really get it why it doesn't work if the pull is not about to break anything. If that's a security concern, then why does it work for new files? In theory, the pull could introduce the new file of the same path.

Is there any solution to make it easier?

Comment: Would love to see your face the first time you attempt to pull and there's a conflict with your files modified on the working tree. In other words, git is watching your back to avoid messing up the modified files.

Comment: One option as of Git 2.6 is to use `git fetch; git rebase --autostash` (or set `git config rebase.autoStash true`) to automatically stash changes before rebasing and pop after the rebase is done.  If there are any conflicts with the pop, you will be left with unresolved conflicts plus a stash named `autostash` from before the rebase; from there you can resolve conflicts as you normally would.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git pull --rebase --autostash`. This essentially stashes your local changes, fetches from a remote, rebases on top of it, and pops the stash in one command.

Note you can also configure these flags to be the default behavior:

```
$ git config pull.rebase true
$ git config rebase.autoStash true
```

But with great power comes great responsibility, use this option only if you're absolutely sure in what you're doing.

Comment: That sounds like an idea. I would prefer to just be warned if there are any conflicting files and merge otherwise though.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that this behavior depends on your configuration.  When using default `pull` behavior - "fetch and merge" - you can have local changes and `pull` will still work as long as the changes-to-merge don't affect the same file(s) as the local changes.

However when doing `rebase` git is more cautious.  You can argue about whether this is necessary, or whether it's more motivated by technical details of what's involved in a `rebase`, that maybe you think the user shouldn't have to care about.  But whatever the case, this is git's behavior.

If you really want this to be automatic, you can use auto-stashing.  The simplest way is to say

```
git pull --autostash
```

If you want it to be even more automatic, you can set the `rebase.autostash` config value to `true`.  However, this makes autostashing the default for *all* rebases within the scope of the config value (i.e. within the repo, or on your machine if you configure this with the `--global` option).  That means you'll get a rebase attempt (and potentially hard-to-untangle conflicts) when you rebase with a dirty work tree.  `autostash` is considered a "use with care" option, so I don't recommend configuring it as the default.

For that matter, even if you just use the `--autostash` argument on `pull`, you should be careful.  Just the fact that you're doing rebase-based pulls is documented as "potentially dangerous", so you need to be sure you know what you're doing when you layer `autostash` on top of that.

Comment: Sometimes I wish git was a little more abstract instead of being a raw tool.